# Get typeof(T) name in constraint method

Tags: c#

I was wondering how to get the typeof(T) name in a constraint method, here is the code:

```
public class SomeItem : ItemBase
{
    ...
}
```

and I wanted to get the type name in this method call:

```
Save<SomeItem>(item);
```

And the method will be:

```
public void Save<T>(T item) where T : ItemBase
{
    var type1 = typeof(T).Name;
    var type2 = typeof(T).FullName;
    var type3 = typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName;
    // this all will return 'ItemBase' type name
}
```

I wanted to get the "SomeItem" type name. Thanks.

#### Solution

I should just do this simple: var typeName = item.GetType().Name;

Oh my...

Comment: I am not sure what you are actually asking? The 1st variable `type1` contains what it is you are asking for so what is your actual question? How to return a string from a method?

Comment: public void Save<T> method know nothing about SomeItem, if you use constraint where T : SomeItem then typeof will show what you need.

Comment: @Igor the 'type1' returns the name 'ItemBase'. I wanted to get the 'SomeItem' type name.

Comment: @Riza: The code you posted returns "SomeItem" for `type1`, not "ItemBase".

Comment: @MichaelLiu Hmm... I create a console app for testing and right, it returns as it is the typeof(T) name. How come in my other project it returns the ItemBase instead of the SomeItem.

Comment: Can you post the code in your other project?

Comment: I add the debug output image in the question.

Comment: *response to update with pic* <- if you are seeing `DomainEvent` then that is the actual type of  the instance that was passed in.

Comment: @Igor I add another image of what I'm expecting for the typeof(T) name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the compile-time declaration:

```
T item
```

the expression:

```
typeof(T).Name
```

gives the name of the compile-time type when `T` was inferred (or given explicitly), whereas:

```
item?.GetType().Name
```

gives the name of the actual run-time type (or `null`).

---

Note: Neither technique gives the type from the base-class constraint. That might well be a completely different type. Example:

```
class B
{
}
class C : B
{
}
class D : C
{
}
```

and some method elsewhere:

```
void M<T>(T t) where T : B
{
  var x = typeof(T);
  var y = t?.GetType();
}
```

if we do this:

```
var d = new D();
C c = d;
M(c);
```

then when this is compiled, we get `M<C>(c);`, so the type parameter `T` is substituted with `C`. But the run-time type is `D` (we had `new D()`). So inside the method, `x` stands for `C`, and `y` stands for `D`. The type `B` from the constraint is not relevant there.

Comment: You are right. I totally forgot just to get the type name from the object. Thanks man.

Comment: @Riza I put some more details in. The constraint part was a red herring; it was not because of the constraint you got `ItemBase`. And your question is misleading because it says `Save<SomeItem>(item);` but that is not what you have in your real code. You likely have an `item` whose compile-time type (hold mouse over when _not_ debugging) is `ItemBase`, but whose actual run-time type happens to be `SomeItem`. Note that calling a generic method __is not dynamic__.

Comment: Not at all, the item type name are saved to database showing the base class instead of some T type name. That is the issue and exactly the same output as the debugging. It is still like that now, but your solution to just get from the item GetType() itself is actually what I need and I totally forgot. As in my example, I use the Save<SomeItem>(item), actually you can just do Save(item) as long as the type inherit the ItemBase class. However, I missed writing the interface code part in the question which is
void Save<T>(T @event) where T : ItemBase;